# Non-swappable memory allocation in Java

Tags: java

I know this is a long shot but I need to construct a secure temporary object and one thought was to construct a buffer in memory that will not get swapped out to the drive.  Is this possible in Java?

Comment: swapping to drive is done by OS not by java i believe.. why does that effect you anyways?

Comment: Purely out of interest. It's the problem of the OS, not the JVM.

Comment: Possibly Irrelevant Side Node: using an encrypted swap with a random key gives you session to session security on any swapped out pages.

Comment: This is definitely not an OS issue. Using native libraries you can allocate a memory block which is declared as non-swappable to the OS. This protects against some attacks where you force the OS to swap to get an on disk image of your process memory.

Comment: From the answers provided, it appears that you cannot allocate memory in Java that is guaranteed not to be swapped.  But even if there was a platform independent way of doing this (e.g. `noswap String s = "I am secure.";`), what would you do with the object?  If you call some method like `System.out.println(s)` you have **no** guarantee that `println` doesn't use some buffer that is subject to swapping.  Similarly methods used to read the "secure" object from a persistent store would also likely use buffers and such that are swappable.  Even garbage could be swapped before being reallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: No.

You may try JNI to interact directly with the host OS (of course this won't be platform independent).

Answer (score 2):

NIO supports a type of ByteBuffer usually known as a direct buffer. Direct buffers can essentially be used like any other ByteBuffer (and are implemented as a ByteBuffer subclass), but have the property that their underlying memory is allocated outside the Java heap.

But from know on, the buffer is under the control of OS. So as far as I know you could not direct OS not to swap it.